# iOS9 What is the proper way to update AFNetworking calls to work with HTTPS (error -1200 , -9824)?

Tags: ssl, https, afnetworking-2, ios9, nserror

I'm switching from iOS8 to iOS9 and AFNetworking web service calls over HTTPS that worked before no longer work. I'm getting `error -1200` and `error -9824` The issue is related to using self-signed certificates.

> Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "An SSL error has
>   occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=[server url],
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server
>   anyway?, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9824

I see this related question: [IOS9 SSL error with NSURLSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31505808/ios9-ssl-error-with-nsurlsession), with the following answer, however, the answer is cryptic and does not really tell me how to fix the issue.

> ATS trusts only certificate signed by a well known CA, all others are
>   rejected. As a consequence the only solution with a Self signed
>   certificate is to set anexception with NSExceptionDomains.

**What is the proper way to update AFNetworking calls to work with HTTPS on iOS9?**

In the past I've used numerous workarounds, including a way to respond to `NSURLAuthenticationChallenge`, however I'm looking for something more definitive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

iOS 9 forces connections that are using HTTPS to be TLS 1.2 to avoid recent vulnerabilities. In iOS 8 even unencrypted HTTP connections were supported, so that older versions of TLS didn't make any problems either. As a workaround, you can add this code snippet to your Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
  <dict>  
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>  
  <true/>  
  </dict>
```

Thereby you're disabling the App Transport Security. Hope that's helpful.

Here's a potential solution, (but still does not work in the case above) [How can I add NSAppTransportSecurity to my info.plist file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216758/how-can-i-add-nsapptransportsecurity-to-my-info-plist-file)

Answer (score -1):

Allowing Invalid SSL Certificates

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES; // not recommended for production
```

Comment: Not sure this works, as ATS still rejects the request/response.