# AFNetworking need to bypass ssl checking

Tags: ios, ssl, https, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I have an app that connects directly to hardware routers. Since `iOS 9` I updated `AFNetworking` and now I am getting `ssl` errors when I attempt to connect over `https`.

This isn't an `iOS 9` `App Transport Security` issue, as I have added the relevant `.plist` entry to bypass it and connections work fine over `http`.

I need to bypass certificate checking as each router has it's own self signed certificate, so I obviously can't add the certificates to my app as every users is different.

I use a `AFHTTPRequestOperation` subclass for connections and have set `self.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;` but I get the following error:

> Error during connection: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An
>   SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be
>   made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server
>   anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa9f3611b40 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred
>   and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://myserver.com:4780/Info.htm,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server
>   anyway?, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9806,
>   _kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure
>   connection to the server cannot be made., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://myserver.com:4780/Info.htm,
>   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://myserver.com:4780/Info.htm,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://myserver.com:4780/Info.htm,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}

I've also tried adding `setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock:` however the block never gets called.

Can someone please help?

Thanks

EDIT -----
Setting `self.securityPolicy.validatesDomainName = NO;` also doesn't work. I wonder if it's a problem with the type of certificate on the hardware.

EDIT 2 -----
Here's the certificate

> New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DES-CBC3-SHA  Server public key is 2048
>   bit  Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported  Compression: NONE 
>   Expansion: NONE  SSL-Session:  Protocol : SSLv3  Cipher : DES-CBC3-SHA
>   Session-ID:
>   010000000C6B8632215649C0665E9DCC9EC59E22F8F021672B6B50B84222A342 
>   Session-ID-ctx:  Master-Key:
>   D71EC7D8F7A4A3581E25CDAD9C532B2C7B4DA8B513AF337095496B575F525CFBA02A40797B2D2A4F0B5911EFEFC3623F
>   Key-Arg : None  Start Time: 1443102149  Timeout : 300 (sec)  Verify
>   return code: 18 (self signed certificate)

EDIT 3 --------
Adding this code to my `AFHTTPRequestOperation` subclass makes it work on iOS 8, however the block isn't even called on iOS 9.

```
[self setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock:^(NSURLConnection * _Nonnull connection, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge * _Nonnull challenge)
    {
        NSLog(@"**** HERE ****");
        if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
        {
            [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
        [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }];
```

Comment: What ATS plist entries have you added?

Comment: `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads = True` before adding this, even http connections failed. I believe the ATS is just to force http connections to use https.

Comment: Hmm.  This duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634986/ios9-what-is-the-proper-way-to-update-afnetworking-calls-to-work-with-https-err suggests that same fix, but the answer isn't accepted

Comment: This one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31505808/ios9-ssl-error-with-nsurlsession says that you can only support self-signed certs with exception domains, but I have an app that is working with self-signed certs and just NSAllowsArbitraryLoads.  It isn't using AFNetworking though

Comment: I believe `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` overrides `NSExceptionDomains`. `NSExceptionDomains` is just a more refined option.

Comment: Have you set `self.securityPolicy.validatesDomainName=NO;`

Comment: Yes I have tried adding that also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90218/discussion-between-paulw11-and-darren).

Comment: @Darren did you try to set `self.allowsInvalidSSLCertificate = YES;` in your subclass of `AFHTTPRequestOperation`?

Comment: `allowsInvalidSSLCertificate` is not found. I also tried searching for it, and it's only found once in AFNetworking and that is in a comment ` If `allowsInvalidSSLCertificate` is set to YES, `connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:` will attempt to have the challenge sender use credentials with invalid SSL certificates.`

Answer (score 3):

```
AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeNone];
securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
manager.securityPolicy = securityPolicy;
```

Comment: i have deleted another answer.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered similar problems and in my case I solved it setting the security policy to **AFSSLPinningModeNone** and obviously allowing the invalid certificates.

An example in Obj-C:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeNone];
securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
manager.securityPolicy = securityPolicy;

[manager POST:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
    NSLog(@"Response: %@",responseObject);
}
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I think the cert is just too outdated.

Answer (score 1):

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/index.html):

> Default Behavior
>
> All connections using the NSURLConnection, CFURL, or NSURLSession APIs
> use App Transport Security default behavior in apps built for iOS 9.0
> or later, and OS X v10.11 or later. Connections that do not follow the
> requirements will fail. For more information on various the connection
> methods, see NSURLConnection Class Reference, CFURL Reference, or
> NSURLSession Class Reference.
>
> These are the App Transport Security requirements:
>
> The server must support at least Transport Layer Security (TLS)
> protocol version 1.2. Connection ciphers are limited to those that
> provide forward secrecy (see the list of ciphers below.) Certificates
> must be signed using a SHA256 or greater signature hash algorithm,
> with either a 2048-bit or greater RSA key or a 256-bit or greater
> Elliptic-Curve (ECC) key. Invalid certificates result in a hard
> failure and no connection. These are the accepted ciphers:
>
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

You might want to upgrade the security settings in your hardware to be compatible with above and/or set `NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion` to **TLSv1.0**

Comment: Unfortunately, the hardware cannot be updated. The app connects to users home routers.

Comment: Surely disabling ATS using the plist entry should override all the ATS stuff?

Comment: don't disable, set the minimum accepted version instead.

Comment: Setting the minimum is being more refined than disabling. However disabling doesn't fix the error, so setting the minimum won't either. Besides, minimum TLS Version is a setting for individual domains (I don't know the domain in advance).

Answer (score 0):

In your subclass of AFHTTPRequestOperation, implement the following:

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{

    if ([protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
        return YES;
    }

   return  [super connection:connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{

    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
        [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        return;
    }

    return [super connection:connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

Comment: I've added them and added a log and they don't even get called.

Comment: It seems them methods have been deprecated. I tried adding the protocol but they still weren't called.

Comment: please refer to my other answer

Answer (score 0):

To allow Invalid SSL Certificate with AFNetworking. Add the following line in AFURLConnectionOperation.h below #import Availability.h

## define _AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_ 1

Comment: As of version 1.2.1, you don't need anymore to set this define. Instead you can set the 'allowsInvalidSSLCertificate' property to YES on AFHTTPRequestOperation, which is much more convenient

Comment: [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager].securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;                              In AFNetworking 2.0, you can use the following: